# How to get the first element and the second element of given any tuple?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be any set which could be considered a tuple -- that is, $A = (B, C)$ holds for some sets $B$ and $C$. Then what expression can find $B$ and $C$? I mean that an expression is a set whose existence is guaranteed by the axioms of ZFC. So, what I want is to find $\mathrm{fst}$ and $\mathrm{snd}$ such that $A = \left( \mathrm{fst} A, \mathrm{snd} A \right)$.

*Added*: We use Kuratowski's definition of ordered pair - i.e., $(a,b):=\{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$

Comment: See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a tuple $T = (x, y) = \{\{x\}, \{x,y\}\}$, observe that $\bigcup T = \{x, y\}$ by the axiom of union. So we would have
$$
x = \bigcup \left\{\, a \in \bigcup T : \{a\} \in T \,\right\}
$$
using the separation and pairing axioms.
We can then use this $x$ to obtain
$$
y = \bigcup \left\{\, a \in \bigcup T : (x, a) = T \,\right\}
$$
again using the separation and pairing axioms.

There won't be an issue if $x = y$, because then we would have $T = \{\{x\}\}$ and $\bigcup T = \{x\}$.